# Optimizing a 3D-Loop (C++)

Tags: c++, optimization, scientific-computing

I'm working on a multigrid solver in C++ and right now I'm trying to improve the serial performance. Most time-consuming part in this is the smoother, which in my case is a successive over-relaxation solver. This looks as follows (I hope it is quite self explanatory):

```
int idx; 
int strideY = stride_[level][0];
int strideZ = stride_[level][1];
for(int i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {

    for(int z = 1; z <= innerGridpoints_[level][2]; ++z) {
        for(int y = 1; y <= innerGridpoints_[level][1]; ++y) {
            idx = getIndexInner(level, 1,y,z);
            for(int x = 1; x <= innerGridpoints_[level][0]; ++x, ++idx) {
                grid[idx] = (1. - omega)  * grid[idx] + omega * 1./6. * (grid[idx+1] + grid[idx-1] +
                                    grid[idx + strideY]  + grid[idx - strideY] + 
                                    grid[idx + strideZ]  + grid[idx - strideZ] - 
                                    spacing_[level] * spacing_[level] * rhs[idx]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already made a few optimizations: The loops are positioned such that the inner loop gives the most local entries (i.e. neighboring elements are along the x dimension), and the precalculation of idx (even though this is an inline function, it saved quite some time this way).
I also tried blocking, i.e., not iterating over the whole grid, but only over small chunks to increase locality, but that did not have any influence.
Last idea I have is to try some loop unrolling, but I actually don't expect big improvements from that. I was thinking that maybe there are some possible improvements towards memory access. Any tipps welcome :)

Just FYI: The gridsize will vary from very small up to 255x255x255. Also, the grid has some boundaries in every dimension, consisting of a small number of rows, i.e., the iteration is not over the whole grid.

Comment: Do you intend for the smoothing at (10,10,10) to change the results at (10,10,11) in the same smoothing pass?

Comment: @Yakk: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean? smoothing at (10, 10, 10) right now changes only this value. Do you mean something like Red-Black? This is ususally used for parallelization, but I keep purely serial

Comment: No, I mean you modify `grid[10,10,10]`, then later read this value when setting `grid[10,10,11]` (I'm using `[a,b,c]` to mean "do all the index calculations to find the place where the item at a,b,c is -- `grid[getIndexInner(level, 10,10,10)]` instead of `grid[10,10,10]` is just being verbose)

Comment: I think I get what you mean: Yes, that's perfectly fine. In fact, this is the difference between Gauss-Seidel smoothing and Jacobi smoothing (SOR being a variant of the first)

Comment: Ah:  Well that sort of sucks, because it places a rather insane ordering requirement on your operations.  In effect, the order at which you do your smoothing is nearly completely determined, because data `1,1,1` doesn't depend on anything except adjacent values, while `n,n,n`'s value depends on a huge number of pixels.  Massive asymmetries, ridiculously long dependency chains, and inelegant closed form expressions.

Comment: First make it work. The code seems to IIR filter the entry grid[idx] _inplace_, and then move to next entry [idx+1] and use the previously processed data as input to next cell. This makes the processing anisotropic, which may be your purpose, but I doubt it. The bottleneck anyway is reading the 6 (or 7) entries in the inner loop. That can be reduced by storing the elements in the direction of movement: `grid[idx-1 .. idx+1]` in temporary variables (and rotating them).

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen +1 for "First make it work"

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Same as I told Yakk: It works perfectly fine. This is the way Gauss Seidel works (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method), by using the already updated gridpoints for the iteration step to improve convergence

Comment: In that case, one further option to try is to precalculate grid[n-x]+grid[n+x] over y and z -dimensions. That'll reduce the burden a bit in the inner loop. (+ cache the values grid[n-1 .. n+1])

Answer (score 7):

A good optimizing compiler will do most of the easy things for you anyway, so *always* measure if the changes you're making actually improve things. And, inspect (and learn to understand) the generated assembly code to see what the compiler is actually doing.

But there are a few things I'd try, as the expression is complex, and even good optimizers sometimes need a bit of help:-

First, hoisting subexpressions that are invariant within the inner loop out to the surrounding loop. In you example, the obvious ones are  `spacing_[level] * spacing_[level]` and `omega * 1./6.`

The other thing to try is to make idx be a pointer rather than an array index, and increment the pointer in your loop.

```
 int *idx = &grid[getIndexInner(level, 1,y,z)];  // assuming grid is array of ints.
```

Your expression then starts to look like this

```
*idx = (1. - omega)  * *idx + omega * 1./6. * (idx[1] + idx[-1] +
                                idx[strideY]  + idx[- strideY] + // etc...
```

Your optimizer (assuming it's turned on???) may well be doing this already. But it's worth a shot. As I said, without measurements this is a pointless exercise.

And, as @AkiSuihkonen mentions in the comments above "First make it work". Debugging highly optimized code is much more difficult, so make sure you have your algorithm performing *exactly* how it should be before you start worrying about performance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll def. give it a try. Of course I measure every step I take, so far the optimizations I mentioned always gave me some speedup